# Issues arising when using UnitSimplify for getting a dimensionless expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, units, dimension-reduction

I am having some difficulties when using  `UnitSimplify` in manipulating expressions for obtaining dimensionless quantities in Mathematica 12.0.0. Here is a minimal example showing the difficulty:

```
UnitSimplify[
  Quantity[10, "Joules"^(-1)] 
   (Quantity[20, "Joules"] r^2 + 
    Quantity[30, "Gigapascals" ("Picometers")^(3/2)] Sqrt[d^2 Quantity[40, "Liters"] +  
    f^2 Quantity[50, "Liters"]])]
```

The  `UnitSimplify` appears to do nothing above. To solve this difficulty, I have worked out the unit conversion factor for turning  `"Gigapascals" ("Picometers")^(3/2)` into `"Joules"^(1) "Liters"^(-1/2)`. Then I applied a rule.

```
% /. Quantity[x_, "Gigapascals" ("Picometers")^(3/2)] -> 
       UnitConvert[
         Quantity[x, "Gigapascals" ("Picometers")^(3/2)], 
         "Joules"^(1) "Liters"^(-1/2)]
```

Now that I can see that the units cancel, I can just take the magnitudes and find the dimensionless expression.

My question is: can this replacement rule be made more general to avoid working out unit conversion factors every time I come up with a dimensionless expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica is assuming that your variables `r`, `d` and `f` are quantities with dimensions, and so it gives up. If you tell Mathematica that they are unitless quantities, then it will work:

```
UnitSimplify[
    Quantity[10,"Joules"^(-1)] *
    (
        Quantity[20,"Joules"] Quantity[r,"Unities"]^2 +
        Quantity[30,"Gigapascals" ("Picometers")^(3/2)] *
        Sqrt[
            Quantity[d,"Unities"]^2Quantity[40,"Liters"] +
            Quantity[f,"Unities"]^2 Quantity[50,"Liters"]
        ]
    )
]
```

> 10 ((3 Sqrt[40 d^2 + 50 f^2])/(1000000000 Sqrt[10]) + 20 r^2)

Comment: Thanks! I take it that "Unities" is the unit for dimensionless quantities.

Comment: I *think* you can also use "DimensionlessUnit".